# how to add a 2 links on 1 line using a li element inside sidebar using bootstrap dashboard

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i'm using this example as guideline http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/
But now i want to modify the sidebar so i could get 2 links in one line. i tryed something like this :

I'm using AngularJS to show what `<li>` is active

```
<li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/content1')}" > 
    <a href="#/content1">Content1  </a> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#/content1/addsomestuff">+</a>
</li>
```

But this does display on 2 lines in the sidebar instead of 1.

Is it also possible to give the first part on 80% of the space and the second part 20% of the place inside the sidebar?
this is how i think it should look inside the `<li>` element

[image]

Comment: You do not provide enough information. But is sounds like the display for li anchor tag needs to be set to  `li a{display: inline-block; float: left;}`

Comment: Testing bootstrap CSS only http://jsfiddle.net/ja9uLtyw/, it works as intended with no CSS change. So please add more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the below CSS to achieve that -

```css
li a{
        float:left;
        display: block;
    }

    li a:first-child{
        width: 79%;
    }

    li a:last-child{
        width: 19%;
        margin-left: 2%;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li class="clearfix" ng-class="{ active: isActive('/content1')}" > <a href="#/content1" class="btn btn-warning">Content1  </a> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#/content1/addsomestuff">+</a>  </li>
```

I used `btn-warning` class to show you that its both element taking the width as you are trying to get. Instead of applying css on `li a` give the `li` a class and apply the css. Also use bootstrap `clearfix` class in that `li` as both `a` are float element

Comment: Thanks for this example, Now i know how to modify this.